# Grails integration test of controllers (for rest api) not working

Tags: rest, grails, integration-testing

Grails 2.4.4. 
We have a lot of JSON/REST API end points like the one below, but with a lot more code (NOTE: We cant use RestfulController because we have SpringSecurity and they are not compatible)

e.g.

```
class SessionController 
def sessionService
static namespace = 'v1'
static allowedMethods = [loginPlayer: "POST"]

def loginPlayer()  {
    def payload = request.JSON

    try {
        // Check params are there.
        if (payload.user == null) {
            render(status: 422, contentType: 'application/json') {
                 [
                  'result'     : -1
                  'description': "missing params"
                 ]
            return
        }

        def result = sessionService.loginPlayer(
                    payload.user,
                    payload.password
            )

        if (result.returnCode == 0) {
                render(status: 200, contentType: 'application/json') {
                    [
                      'result' : 0
                      'authToken' : result.authToken
       etc.
```

We are currently testing them all by hand using SOAPUI. We desperately want automated integration tests, which test the entire API end to end against the DB.

We tried this:

```
class SessionControllerIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    SessionController controller
    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test login"() {
        controller = new SessionController()
        controller.request.contentType = 'application/json'
        controller.request.format = 'json'
        controller.response.format = 'json'

        when:
        controller.request.content =
                '{"user":"someuser","password":"somepass"}'.getBytes()

        def model = controller.loginPlayer()

        then:
        model != null
    }
}
```

But it always returns null as the model.

Also tried:

```
class SessionControllerIntegrationSpec extends GroovyTestCase {
:
def sessionService
:
controller.sessionService = sessionService
```

As per instructions to pass in "[testing controllers with services](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting)"

But this didn't help - result still null.  Also extending GroovyTestCase means going back to assertions.

Is what we are trying to do even possible?

We see that some people are integration testing by hitting the external URLs of the localhost, e.g.:

```
class ExampleWebAppSpecification extends Specification {
    def "Should return 200 & a message with the input appended"() {

        setup:
             def primerEndpoint = new RESTClient( 'http://localhost:8080/' )
        when:
             def resp = primerEndpoint.get([ path: 'exampleendpoint', query : [ input : 'Get a hair cut' ]])
        then:
             with(resp) {
                 status == 200
                 contentType == "application/json"
             }
             with(resp.data) {
                 payload == "Something really important: Get a hair cut"
             }
    } }
```

This is not a lot different to using jmeter or other tool to test a running server, and has a lot of dependencies.

Any tips or suggestions?

UPDATE 1:

found an example which does this

```
 assert controller.response.getStatus() == 200
```

In the debugger, controller.response.getStatus()  returns 405 (a status our controller never returns) and controller.response.contentAsString returns "".

When we run tests in the debugger, the Controllers code is never called. So the problem might be grails is not injecting the SessionController at all.

UPDATE 2

Guessing that the problem is with the request methods, tried adding this:

```
    controller.request.requestMethod = HttpMethod.POST
```

However, this still generates 405.

In the REST controller, we have this:

```
static allowedMethods = [loginPlayer: "POST"]
```

If I comment this out, I get the expected response!

So the problem is now how to get the test to use POST (setting requestMethod does not seem to do it), or how to change the controller to accept GET if its in test mode?

UPDATE 3 - SOLVED! Working code below:

class SessionControllerIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec
    def sessionService

```
class SessionControllerIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    SessionController controller

    void "test login"() {
        controller = new SessionController() // must manually create
        controller.sessionService = sessionService // must manually inject

        controller.request.contentType = 'application/json'
        controller.request.format = 'json'
        controller.response.format = 'json'
        controller.request.requestMethod = HttpMethod.POST
        controller.request.method = 'POST'


        when:
        controller.request.content =
                '{"user":"someuser","password":"somepass"}'.getBytes()

        then:
        assert controller.response.getStatus() == 200
        print "CONTENT: " + controller.response.contentAsString
        // now can use string search functions to check the JSON data returned.
```

Comment: We are doing full testing of REST api of our application. Just do this in your functional tests not integration tests. You can use RESTClient as in your last code snipped. It works both on local computer and on continous integration server

Comment: Thanks Droggo.  Are you saying our integration test code will work as a functional test, or that we need to switch to using the RESTClient strategy, and not try to call controllers methods direct (which doesn't seem to work at all).  There is almost zero documentation for integration tests, which is a big shame as they are very effective.

Comment: Hi John, sorry for being not clear. Functional testing with RestClient imitates external application calling your API. This is the test we are doing, and which gives us exactly what we want. In this situation you can also easily set request method to POST if needed. I will check if we have any integration test, testing the API and let you know if found out.

Comment: In controller unit test you use: request.method = 'POST', did you try that in integration test?